# Itering through DataFrame columns and deleting a row if cell value is not a number

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following csv file that I converted to a DataFrame:

```
apartment,floor,gasbill,internetbill,powerbill
401,4,120,nan,340
409,4,190,50,140
410,4,155,45,180
```

I want to be able to iterate each column, and if the value of a cell **in internetbill column** is not a number, delete that whole row. So in this example, the ''401,4,120,nan,340'' row would be eliminated from the DataFrame.

I thought that something like this would work, but I have no avail and I'm stuck

```
df.drop[df['internetbill'] == "nan"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `pd.read_csv` then that `nan` will get imported as a `np.nan`.  If so, then you need `dropna`

```
df.dropna(subset=['internetbill'])

   apartment  floor  gasbill  internetbill  powerbill
1        409      4      190          50.0        140
2        410      4      155          45.0        180
```

If those are strings for whatever reason, you could do one of two things:

1. **`replace`**

   ```
   df.replace({'internetbill': {'nan': np.nan}}).dropna(subset=['internetbill'])
   ```
2. **`to_numeric`**

   ```
   df.assign(
       internetbill=pd.to_numeric(df['internetbill'], errors='coerce')
   ).dropna(subset=['internetbill'])
   ```

Comment: The replace solution throws the following error:
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'

Comment: Then don't use that one (-: